# file upload error

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload video file in php. 
but .avi,mpg,mp4 is working fine, rest of is not uploading.

```
<?php 
        include '../includes/include.php';
        $title          =    $_POST['txtTitlen'];
        $description    =    $_POST['txtDescriptionn'];
        $product    =    $_POST['selProductn'];
        $speciality =    $_POST['selSpecialityn'];
        $type       =        $_POST['selMedTypen'];
        $temp_img       =        $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $date           =   date("Y-m-d  H:i:s", time());

        $img=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
   if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/dat") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avi")|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mov") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avi") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/wmv") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mkv") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/wmx")|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpeg")|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpg") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 150000)) 
        {
        echo move_uploaded_file($temp_img, "video/$img");
        }
        else
        {
        echo "File Loading Error...";
        }
            $sql="INSERT INTO tblmedia(medTitle,medDesc,medType,medSpeciality,medProduct,medIsActive,insDate,modDate,medPath) VALUES('".$title."','".$description."','".$type."','".$speciality."','".$product."','0','".$date."','".$date."','".$img."');";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
        header('Location:../media/');
        ?>
```

Comment: What do you get in `$_FILES["file"]["error"]`?

Comment: what do you mean by `but .avi,mpg,mp4 is working fine, rest of is not uploading.` ??

Comment: Do you have the wrong MIME types for the file types that aren't working?

Comment: i mean .avi, .mpg and mp4 files uploaded successfully. But not all other extensions are not uploaded.

Comment: How can you say the files did not upload? I don't see that you actually process the file upload error variable. I'd say you need to add some **basic** error checking first. Please see: [PHP File-Upload: Error Messages Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepending "video/" will not always give you the correct mime type of the video format.

See the following links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_video

http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_type_parameters#MIME_types_used_in_the_wild_.28in_type.3D.22.22.29

Answer (score 0):

Try using TamperData Addon for Firefox and check the MIME type you are sending. Then you can add the correct types for the files that are not working.